# how to restrict an object to only have value as string in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to create an object that only has string as its value. so I need to convert date object to string (ISO 8601 format). I make a method like this inside a class

```
toPayloadData() : Map<string, string> {

    // all the payload  data that need to be sent via FCM should be in string

    return {
        body: this.body,
        createdAt: this.createdAt.toISOString(), // convert Date to ISO 8601 string format
        creatorID: this.creatorID,
        creatorImageURL: this.creatorImageURL,
        creatorName: this.creatorName,
        title: this.title,

    };
}
```

as you can see, I use `: Map<string, string>` above, in order to give error if I put value that is not string.

but I have error like this:

```
Type '{ body: string; createdAt: string; creatorID: string; creatorImageURL: string; creatorName: string; title: string; }' 

is not assignable to type 'Map<string, string>'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'body' does not exist in type 'Map<string, string>'.
```

in Kotlin, Swift and Dart, I can restrict it like that, but I guess the object and Map is different in Typescript

so what is the return type of my method above so I can only return an object that has string value

```
return {
  key1: "string in here",
  key2: "string in here",
}
```

Comment: Use `Record` instead of `Map`. You want to describe a type. A Map is a particular object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Record<string, string>` as a readable built-in type.

This is a shorthand for a constructed type like this: `{ [key: string]: string }`. Meaning an object with keys of type string, each with a value of type string.

```
toPayloadData() : Record<string, string> {
    return {
        body: this.body,
        createdAt: this.createdAt.toISOString(), // convert Date to ISO 8601 string format
        creatorID: this.creatorID,
        creatorImageURL: this.creatorImageURL,
        creatorName: this.creatorName,
        title: this.title,

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface containing the properties you want to return
eg

```
export interface ICreationDetails{
        body: string;
        createdAt: string;
        creatorID: string;
        creatorImageURL: string;
        creatorName: string;
        title: string;
}
```

Then just return this from the method:

```
toPayloadData() : ICreationDetails {
YOUR_METHOD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In js we have a data structur called `Map` and it's different than a normal object, and `typescript` is just a static type tool to check your code types at author time.

First solution is to use map correctly

```js
function toPayloadData1(): Map<string, string> {


    const resultMap = new Map<string, string>();

    resultMap.set('title', 'only string accepted');

    return resultMap;
}
```

Another solution is not to use a `Map` and instead a plain object with the proper typing

```js
function toPayloadData2(): { [key: string]: string } {


    return {
        title: 'only string accepted'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Record type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

```
toPayloadData() : Record<string, string> {
...
}
```

You could also use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but in this case you would also need to instantiate a `Map`.

```
const map = new Map<string, string>();
map.set('body', this.body);
...
```